# Single table or double table - Better performance with?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to create a system to save user's vote for two different type of module: `News` and `Video`.

This table should have the same fields:

```
id  
entry_id  
vote  
user_id
```

So I tought to add a new field to save also the name of the module (`module`), in this way I can have just one table in the DB and filter it when needed and create two `views` for statistic purpose.

I don't really know if the best solution is one table with the new field or is better have two different table.

Let's assume that I have `1000` news and `1000` users and all of them will vote each news I will have `1000000` rows in the table.
Now assume that I have also `1000` videos and also in this case all my users will vote it, other `1000000` rows for an amount of `2000000` rows in a single table.

Do I have any performance problem in this case? And If I will have much more video, news an users?

Operation that I should do:

1. Insert
2. Update
3. Search

If you need more infos please ask

Comment: There is not enough information to give a recommendation other than, when in doubt, normalize.

Comment: So a single table with the module name in it?

Comment: On the basis of the info provided... Single table

Comment: Any other info that will help you to...help me? :)

Comment: Indexes. Indexes. And once again, indexes.

Comment: If your table is properly indexed, then you shouldn't have performance problems with using a single table for this small volume of data, and 2,000,000 rows is small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way to answer this question is based on `entry_id`.  The votes are going to be about *something* and that *something* is going to reference another table.

So, if you have two separate tables for `News` and `Videos`, then you should have two separate `votes` tables.  Neither will have `entry_id`.  One will have `news_id` and the other `video_id`.

If you have one table, say `Entries` for both `News` and `Videos`, then have one table.

In other words, I am advising against having one table conditionally reference multiple other tables.  It becomes very difficult to express foreign key restraints, for one thing.  In addition, `join` operations are cumbersome to express.  Someone else might visit the table and not realize that `entry_id` can refer to multiple tables, and incorrectly set up queries.

All of these problem can be overcome (and there are situations where one table may be the preferred solution).  However, if the original entities are in different tables, then put the votes in different tables.

Comment: Yes, videos and news have different tables. Speaking of a single table I don't think that I should make to many join just because the vote will be show in the single video or single news page and I don't think to use join to get the vote but a view that do that for me. I think that two tables could be the solution, but what do you think about indexes?

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi . . . I think indexes are a great idea when used properly to improve performance and enforce constraints.

Comment: Great, I will go with two tables...do you think that in this case I cann add indexes on `video_id` ( or news ) and `user_id` or are useless? I don't know how much the tables will be big, so maybe indexes will help me in the future